# Entry not updating after button press in tkinter python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I improve this so that it works?

```
import os
import time
import random
import sys
import string
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.title("SecurePass v1.0.0")

welcome = tk.Label(root, text="Welcome to SecurePass v1.0.0")
welcome.pack()

res = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=7))

randPass = tk.Entry(root)
randPass.insert(0, "" + res)
randPass.pack()

def resetText():
    randPass.delete(0, tk.END)
    randPass.insert(0, "" + res)

resetButton = tk.Button(root, text="New Pass...", command=resetText)
resetButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

No matter what I do, the button doesn't update the text field. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always insert the same text. You have to generate new one.

```
def resetText():

    res = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=7))

    randPass.delete(0, tk.END)
    randPass.insert(0, res)
```